# TFS2010 build deploys website even when integration tests fail

Tags: integration-testing

I have a build that I am trying to do in TFS2010 (server 2008R2) and it is not doing what I want it to do. I want the code to build (I have a gated check-in policy) and on successful build I want to run tests(Unit and integration  tests) If (and only if) all tests pass I want the build to be deployed to out IIS7 server.

When starting the setup I started by ignoring tests to see if the build and deploy works. After I had this working I am now trying to get a tests to fail and that must prevent the deployment of the site.

In one of my tests (on purpose) I added Assert.IsTrue(1 == 2); and in the log I can see that the build failed but still the site is deployed to my IIS server. I have my MSBuild Arguments set to : /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent /p:MSDeployServiceUrl=http://111.11.11.111/msdeployagentservice /p:DeployIisAppPath="MVC - Jack" /p:UserName=APP-107\Administrator /p:Password=xxxxxx /p:Configuration=Release

Why is the deploy still happening even if the test fails and I have the build definition set to "Disable Tests = false" and "Fail build on test failure"

Thank you
Jack

Ps. I there maybe and example out there that explains how to modify BuildProcessTemplate.xaml to stop the deploy on failing a tes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSBuild Activity in the DefaultBuildTemplate.xaml runs *before* any of your tests do.  Therefore it will do the same thing always *regardless* of your test results.  To rectify this, add a MSBuild Activity *after* the tests in the DefaultBuildTemplate.xaml in the "If Tests Successful" branch and deploy in that activity.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Problem is that I need to build the test project as part of the build before I can run the tests. I need to determine if the tests passed and based on that I need to either deploy or not. Where would I put that? Any links on how to do this in the xaml?

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a full day I have this partly whipped. I found a sample that closely resembled mine at: http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2011/07/14/TFS-Team-Build-2010-Only-deploying-if-unit-tests-pass.aspx

Now I just have to figure out how to not allow it to build twice. At least I now have unit and integration tests before a deploy.